# Tableau Regular Expression Regexp_Extract() Troubles

Tags: regex, tableau-api

I am trying to use the REGEXP_EXTRACT(string, pattern) function in Tableau 10.0. I have worked with regex before in C, R and python. Tableau just doesn't seem to be cooperating for even the simplest regex, all I can get is "Null". My data source is an Excel spreadsheet (.xlsx). I also tried using a CSV file with the same data to no avail.

Examples:
Players[1] = "Ezekiel Elliott, RB" (r.e the Players dimension contains values of the format [A-z]{1,40},\s[A-Z]{2}). I am trying to capture the last two letters, which contain the player's football position (RB, QB, etc.) in a calculated field.
All following simply return null:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT([Players], '(?<=,\s)[A-Z]{2}')

REGEXP_EXTRACT([Players], '(?<=,\s)[A-Z]{2}')

REGEXP_EXTRACT[[Players], "[e,E]")

REGEXP_EXTRACT("Ezekiel Elliott, RB", "[e,E]")
```

The last two are especially troubling, as I can't even match a letter.

Any solutions, explanations of what I'm doing wrong, or even an arrow pointing in an illuminative direction would be greatly appreciated. I've consulted the reference on ICU regular expressions, http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp, but with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *capture* what you need to extract:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT[[Players], "([A-Z]{2})$")
```

The `([A-Z]{2})$` will match the following:

- `([A-Z]{2})` - matches and captures into Group 1 (what you will get in the end) exactly two ASCII uppercase letters
- `$` - asserts the end of string position.

If you say the entries can be matched with `^[A-Za-z]{1,40},\s([A-Z]{2})$`, you may also use this pattern (here, `^` matches the start of string, `[A-Za-z]{1,40}` will match 1 to 40 ASCII letters, `,` will match a comma, and the rest of the pattern is the same as above). Note that [`[A-z]` matches more than just letters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29771926/3832970).

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed, plus a useful reminder on ASCI characters.